# Java RegEx Question?

Tags: java, regex, split

I have a problem with RegEx in java;

my line is :

```
CREATE CHAN:NAME=BTSM:1/BTS:2/TRX:5/CHAN:7,CHTYPE=TCHF_HLF,FHSYID=FHSY_0
```

and I want this :

```
content [0] = BTSM:1/BTS:2/TRX:5/CHAN:7
content [1] = CHTYPE
content [2] = TCHF_HLF
content [3] = FHSYID
content [4] = FHSY_0
```

I wrote this :

```
String[] content = value.split("^=/:|,|=|,$");
```

but it's not work :(
so kindly inform me about that...
Thanks a lot ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
String[] content = value.replaceFirst("^[^=]*=", "").split("[,=]");
```

should do what you want.

I don't understand how you derived `"^=/:|,|=|,$"` so I can't tell you where you went wrong, but here's a breakdown of what it does.

> ^=/:

This is going to skip the string `=/:` if it occurs at the beginning and stick an empty string at the start of the results.  Perhaps you wanted a character set.  `[=/:]` is a character set that matches any occurence of one of those characters.

> ,

This will split on any comma.

> =

This will split on any equals sign.

> ,$

This will skip a comma at the end of the input (or just before a newline at the end of input) and if skipped will stick an empty string on the end of the split result.

Comment: +1 Simple, I like it. RegEx isn't the tool to solve all problems.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what the Hell that thing you're passing to `split()` is, but what you need to do is to split on any occurence of `,` or `=` after removing everything up through the first `=`.  This can be accomplished with:

```
String[] content = (value.substring(value.indexOf('=') + 1)).split("[,=]");
```

Comment: Ooh, even better. Simple always makes me happy =)